# Using GitHub as a work experience portfolio

Tags: github, repository

Would using GitHub as a work experience portfolio, including personal projects in various languages/frameworks, be a good practice when seeking employment?

Comment: This is a primarily opinion-based question and as such [not well suited](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for Stackoverflow, maybe you could try to post it on http://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You'll want to target the specific companies you are applying to, as well. For example, does the company you are targeting value, use, or promote open source projects? Then find some contributions you can make, especially if that company has their own open source projects on GitHub.com.

Definitely host your own projects with a very clear README.md that explains the purpose of the project, anything that showcases design decisions you made, and clear instructions on how to launch/run your project.

Answer (score 1):

No, Since **github** functions as a site where you host your codes, employers won't have time to access and examine each of your codes.

Comment: if employer is passionate about coding and extra development like open source project contribution and other then definitely that will  be plus point.

Comment: Placing codes might help at some point. May not be always. There is no straight answer "Yes" and "No". But good to use this as an option

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
Your future employer may not check out your code, but it will prove that development is your hobby and not only your job.

Put your github repo link in your resume